# Inline definition list with multiple dd elements to 1 dt element

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

Done some Googling and Stackoverflowing on this subject, but I haven't found quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking to use CSS to style a definition list that has multiple dd elements in an inline style. What I mean is I need this:

```
DT first definition term:         DD term 1-1 // DD term 1-2 // DD term 1-3
DT second definition term:        DD term 2-1
DT third definition term:         DD term 3-1 // DD term 3-2 // DD term 3-3 // DD term 3-4 // DD
                                  term 3-5
.
.
DT twenty-first definition term:  DD term 21-1 // DD term 21-2
```

I can only find examples of where there's a 1-to-1 pairing of DT to DD, but nothing that can show multiple DD elements inline.

(Notice above, for the third list, that when there's a new line, the items are always indented flush with each other.)

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Example of what I'm getting:

[image]

The red circled items are "Buy from author" (dt) and its dd elements. The blue ones are "Buy book" (dt) and its dd elements. You can see how they're mixed together.

To the red-circled DD elements, I've applied `display: inline-block;` and `margin: 0;` (without the margin setting, there's a huge indent).

Sorry I can only include a photo. The code and CSS are inside a sandbox site that you can't access without username/password creds.

Comment: *"The code and CSS are inside a sandbox site that you can't access without username/password creds."* If you have access, F12 then copy and paste. If you don't have access...How do you know the page had `<dl>`?

Answer (score 1):

Make `<dd>` inline-block and `<dt>` element inline. By default they are block element. Now insert line breaks via pseudo element on `<dt>`

```css
dt {
  display: inline;
  margin-right:20px;
}

dt::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
 
}

dd {
  display: inline;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
  <dl>
    <dt>Buy from author::</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//Black hot drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//Black hot drink</dd>
    
    <dt>Milk:</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
    <dt>Coffee:</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
    <dt>Milk:</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
    <dd>//White cold drink</dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: As I said above, I'm looking to see how to do it with CSS. But when I use `display: inline-block,` the dd elements run into other dt elements where everything will appear on the same line, where the dd elements will mix into the dt and dd's below it.

Comment: @SteveG. show us an example of the problem you see

Comment: @SteveG. Now it should work. Just in case you want more detail on line break: https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/

Comment: Added an example above in the main body, @Adriano.

Comment: @Adriano It didn't work even now, what changes you want to see in the result, after this, please tell. Should i add // between each of them.

Comment: Have a look at css grid (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp), and perhaps play around with the positioning of `<dt>` and `<dd>`.

Comment: `content: "\A";` hack no longer works in Chrome in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of blocks instead of line-breaks using a variation on the original answer.

```css
dl,
dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

dt,
dd {
  display: inline;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dt::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>English</dt>
  <dd>coffee</dd>
  <dt>Dutch</dt>
  <dd>koffie</dd>
  <dt>Ottoman Turkish</dt>
  <dd>قهوه (kahve)</dd>
  <dt>Arabic</dt>
  <dd>قَهْوَة (qahwah)</dd>
  <dd>قَهِيَ (qahiya) [to lack hunger]</dd>
</dl>
```

If you desire a layout with terms and definitions aligned in two columns, `display: grid;` seems like the best option, as some comments have suggested. There are a lot of great resources for css grid on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) and [Grid By Example](https://gridbyexample.com/). It's an extremely versatile layout!

```css
dl,
dt,
dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "language coffee";
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  grid-column: language;
}

dd {
  grid-column: coffee;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>English</dt>
  <dd>coffee</dd>
  <dt>Dutch</dt>
  <dd>koffie</dd>
  <dt>Ottoman Turkish</dt>
  <dd>قهوه (kahve)</dd>
  <dt>Arabic</dt>
  <dd>قَهْوَة (qahwah)</dd>
  <dd>قَهِيَ (qahiya) [to lack hunger]</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The strucure described sounds alot like a row oriented table with the first column as the header and the rest of the columns are at amounts on each row.

`DL` is the table ...................................................................................................... `display: table`
Then `DIV` are the rows ......................................................................... `display: table-row`
Finally, `DT` and `DD` are cells ................................................................ `display: table-cell`
 *<sup>`<div>` `<template>` and `<script>` [**are VALID**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) as direct children of `<dl>`</sup>*

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

dl {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #bad;
}

div {
  display: table-row;
}

dt,
dd {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2.5px 5px;
  border: 0;
}

dt {
  border-right: 3px solid tomato;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: #cab;
}

dd {
  border-left: 3px dashed #930;
  text-align: left;
  background: #dad;
}

dd:first-of-type {
  border-left: 0;
}

dd:last-of-type {
  border-right: 3px solid tomato;
}

div:first-of-type dt::after,
div:first-of-type dd::after {
  content: ' 1';
}

div:nth-of-type(2) dt::after,
div:nth-of-type(2) dd::after {
  content: ' 2';
}

div:last-of-type dt::after,
div:last-of-type dd::after {
  content: ' 3';
}
```

```html
<DL>
  <DIV>
    <DT>DT</DT>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
  </DIV>
  <DIV>
    <DT>DT</DT>
    <DD>DD</DD>
  </DIV>
  <DIV>
    <DT>DT</DT>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
    <DD>DD</DD>
  </DIV>
```